# AS3 odd or even (mal)function

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

please
how to fix this AS3 function ?

thank you

```
function dispari(numero:int):Boolean;
{
  //check if the number is odd or even
  if (numero % 2 == 0)
  {
    returns false;
  }
  else
  {
    returns true;
  }
}
```

ERROR:
1071: Syntax error: expected a definition keyword (such as function) after attribute returns, not false.

Answer (score 6):

Why do you have a semi-colon `(;)` at the end of your function statement? I don't do *any* AS3 coding but it doesn't look right, and a cursory glance at a few samples on the web don't have it there.

I suspect that may be what's causing your problem. Try this instead:

```
function dispari(numero:int):Boolean
{
    //check if the number is odd or even
    if (numero % 2 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I've also changed the `return` statements to match what every other piece of AS3 does to return values (thanks, @Herms, forgot to mention that :-)

Comment: exactly.  The ; shouldn't be there.

Comment: Oh, also note that it should be "return" not "returns".  This answer's code has it correct.

Answer (score 5):

Pax is correct with there answer, but you can simplify it by just returning the result:

```
function dispari(numero:int):Boolean
{
  return (numero % 2 != 0);
}
```

Comment: or "return (numero % 2 != 0);" ?